# Drop tables with dashes in the name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to delete all tables which name has the pattern '%-%-%-%-%'. The best way to do it I found so far is to do it in 2 steps:

1. Generate the deletion request as by calling the request below

   SELECT ' DROP TABLE ' + REPLACE(TABLE_NAME, '-', NCHAR(8211)) FROM information_schema.tables where TABLE_NAME like '%-%-%-%-%'  ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
2. Run the deletion request.

Unfortunately step 2. does not work. Even if I `REPLACE(TABLE_NAME, '-', NCHAR(8211))`, I still get `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near '0'.` etc.; `0` appreas in the message because the first line of deletion request is `DROP TABLE 0df78d48–c718–49be–ab55–5f158ebdd64c–results`.

Could you help? Thanks!

Comment: sorry for 'tab.les' etc. for somereason I cannot submit/edit a question with the properly written word t-word...

Comment: weird. I've edited your question to replace `tab.le` with `table`

Comment: thanks! Probably becaue if internet explorer issue. Another weird thing about it: I cannot google or live search "drop tabIe" with l instead of I, get a tcp-ip error msg...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Placing square brackets around the table names should give you the result you want.

Example:

```
DROP TABLE [0df78d48–c718–49be–ab55–5f158ebdd64c–results]
```

Comment: you can accomplish this in your query by changing it to:


SELECT ' DROP TABLE [' + TABLE_NAME + ']'  FROM information_schema.tables where TABLE_NAME like '%-%-%-%-%' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME